# Topojson-svg topojson to svg output is upside-down

Tags: svg, d3.js, topojson

**Topojson-svg trial:** I gave it a shoot...

```
curl -o uk.topo.json 'http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/uk.json' #get an online topoJSON file
topojson-svg -o output.svg uk.topo.json    #works !
```

But the `uk.json` => `output.svg` result is a `#000000FF` version of this :

[image: wikiatlas_topojson-svg]

which is UK, right, but with strange circles and inverted uk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Based on [Jason davies' answer](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues/173).*

The problem is that you’re converting unprojected TopoJSON (geographic coordinates) to SVG.

You need the lastest `topojson` code :

```
 sudo npm rm -g topojson
 sudo npm install -g topojson
 topojson --version
```

Should return +1.6.12.

You’ll want to pre-project uk.json first, using topojson. Then, convert the projected TopoJSON to SVG using topojson-svg.

```
curl -o uk.topo.json 'http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/uk.json' #get an online topoJSON file
topojson uk.topo.json --projection='d3.geo.mercator()' -o out.topo.json #works !
topojson-svg -o output.svg out.topo.json    #works !
```

Produce that :

[image: wikiatlas_topojson-svg_reprojected_subunits labels]

The `uk.topojson` containing 2 layers merged from 2 different `topoJSON`, large circles are causes by the `object-places` layer. But the country shapes are doing well.